# ASP.NET Core Azure App Service httpContext.Request.Headers["Host"] Value

Tags: asp.net, azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

Faced strange behaviour today.
We are hosting asp.net core 1.1 web app with Azure App Services and using subdomains that route to a specific controller or area. 
So in my SubdomainConstraint: IRouteConstraint I use

```
HttpContext.Request.Headers["Host"]
```

to get host name. That previously returned smth like that

```
mywebsite.com or subdomain.mywebsite.com
```

Starting today (or a maybe yesterday) it started to return my App Service name instead of host name. On localhost everything works fine.
Enumerating through

```
Context.Request.Headers
```

in one of my Views gives me on localhost:

```
Accept : 
text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding : gzip, deflate, sdch, br
Accept-Language : ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4,ca;q=0.2
Cookie : .AspNetCore.Antiforgery....
Host : localhost:37202
User-Agent : Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 
(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests : 1
```

in Azure App Service:

```
Connection : Keep-Alive
Accept : text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding : gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language : ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4,ca;q=0.2
Cookie : AspNetCore.Antiforgery....
Host : mydeploymentname:80
Max-Forwards : 10
User-Agent : Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests : 1
X-LiveUpgrade : 1
X-WAWS-Unencoded-URL : /
X-Original-URL : /
X-ARR-LOG-ID : 9c76e796-84a8-4335-919c-9ca4rb745f4fefdfde
DISGUISED-HOST : mywebsite.com
X-SITE-DEPLOYMENT-ID : mydeploymentname
WAS-DEFAULT-HOSTNAME : mydeploymentname.azurewebsites.net
X-Forwarded-For : IP:56548
MS-ASPNETCORE-TOKEN : a97b93ba-6106-4301-87b2-8af9a929d7dc
X-Original-For : 127.0.0.1:55602
X-Original-Proto : http
```

I can get what I need from

```
Headers["DISGUISED-HOST"]
```

But having problems with redirects to a login page, it redirects to the wrong URL with my deployment name.

Wondering if I could mess something up anywhere. But we've made last deployment like a few days ago and it worked fine after that.

Comment: Can you share your web app name, either directly or [indirectly](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Reporting-your-site-name-without-posting-it-publicly)? This will help us investigate. Thanks!

Comment: I have the same issue, Microsoft is looking into it.

Comment: Got resolved for me.

Answer (score 2):

This is caused by a regression in AspNetCoreModule deployed to a small number of apps in Azure App Service. This issue is being investigated. Please follow [this thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/88b4c677-5de2-439f-881d-3e1a9c95de5c/failing-redirects-hostname-being-incorrectly-served-to-web-applications?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview) for status.

Here is a workaround you can use until the fix is deployed: in your Configure method (typically in startup.cs), add the following:

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        app.Use((ctx, next) =>
        {
            string disguisedHost = ctx.Request.Headers["DISGUISED-HOST"];
            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(disguisedHost))
            {
                ctx.Request.Host = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HostString(disguisedHost);
            }
            return next();
        });

        // Rest of your code here...

    }
```

Comment: Any update on when this will get fixed?  This is affecting a few of our apps deployed to West US.